# Trying to zip and automatically delete files with "find" and "zip -m" on Linux

Tags: linux, file, zip

there are over 300000 files in the /test folder with a long name (over 30 character )and same header like this "TEST_*" i want to zip all the files into a .zip package and remove them from the /test file.
so i used the command show as below:

```
find ./test -name "TEST_\*" -mtime +1 | zip -m /home/TESTbac.zip -@;
```

but the files in the /test folder still exist after i run the shell script

what i want to ask is why the files still exist after running the script ?
and how can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to pipe the results to the `zip` command. `find` has a `-exec` parameter that will execute the given command for each matching path. I suspect something in the piping process is causing the `-m` to not work as expected.

Instead try this:

```
find ./test -name "TEST_*" -exec zip -m /home/TESTbac.zip '{}' ';'
```

Note: The quoted semicolon denotes the end of the `-exec` command. It's quoted so the command line can differentiate between the ending of the `-exec` command vs the ending of the entire command itself. Meanwhile the {} are automatic replaced by `find` with the matching path results.

Comment: yes i am trying to finding any files with the header of "TEST_\*" any file name matching "TEST_\*"

Comment: @GreenDavid I have revised the answer based on your comments/edits.

Comment: The curly-brackets placeholder `{}` isn't safe.  You should quote it like `'{}'`to protect against file names with embedded whitespace, wildcards and so on.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson I made the change.

Answer (score 2):

```
zip -rm files.zip *.xml
```

This works perfectly

Answer (score -1):

It remain because nothing told it to be deleted.

sudo rmdir /test <- your directory location.

if it gives you guff that there are still files inside it and you still want it gone add a -rf flag to it. RECLUSIVE, meaning all in the tree below it and FORCE -- just do what I told you to.

sudo rmdir /test -rf

Just double check everything is exactly what you want before you do so.

Comment: 1) Yes he did tell it to delete them by using `zip -m`. 2) There is no need to use `sudo`. 3) He wants to remove the files added, not the parent directory. 4) It's "Recursive" not "reclusive". 5) It would be `rm -rf` not `rmdir -rf`. 6) He doesn't say he wants to delete all the files in the directory, only those that go into the zip file.